# Switch between parents - SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my game I have two SKNodes called "Center" rotating.
I have several objects as the child of Center (the SKNode). I did this so I could let these objects orbit around Center. Although at certain points I want to switch to other SKNodes - "Center2". In this I have named one of the objects "Onject", which switched between parents I  need to attach and detach at certain points in my game. I have tried, after doing `self.addChild(Object)` then doing `Center.addChild(Object)`. My game crashed.

How do I switch between parents for objects?

Comment: can you post an example of your code i think the problem you are encountering is because you are trying to assign 2 parents to a node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a method called `move(toParent:SKNode)` to do exactly what you want, it will also fix the coordinates for you.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and should be the accepted one. The other answer is just a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `self.addChild(Object)` and then `Center.addChild(Object)` your game will crash, because the object will then have two parents. You cant add the object twice as a child for different nodes.

If you want to switch the parent, you have to remove it first from its parent, so the flow will be as follows:

- `self.addChild(Object)` (then just perform your game logic)

once its time to switch the parent, follow these steps:

- `Object.removeFromParent()`
- `Center.addChild(Object)`

Then your object has a new parent